# Netbeans + php автоподсказки

Tags: php, netbeans

Для знатоков `NetBeans`:

Есть проект, и понятное дело что дополнительные классы подгружаются не через `include`, а через методы специального класса => `NetBeans` - не видит методы подгружаемого класса и не может подсказать :)

Пример:

```
$this->load('test');

$this->test->[*хочу чтобы в подсказках были функции класса test*].
```

Comment: `/** @var ClassName $variable **/` так тоже не видит?

Comment: @Naumov неа. не видит.

Comment: ну тут только одно используй `phpstorm` он видит :)

Comment: сделал так, над главным классом писал в комментариях @property с моим новым классом, и тогда все работало, ну хоть как-то...

Comment: поставьте шторм зачем такие сложности. это единственнач ide которая без проблем дает подсказки.